# QT Signal Slot Question

Tags: qt, qt4, signals-slots

I have matrix of QLineEdits in a QGridLayout. I want to signal when one of QLineEdits' text changes. I can connect the signal to a slot but there is no way of knowing which QLineEdit was changed. I would like to send the row column number of QLineEdit but there is pass variables to a slot according nokia fourms.

I was wondering if any of you have any suggestions?

One way to do it is to compare old values to new values, but this is inefficient.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [QSignalMapper](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsignalmapper.html) class.  This would allow you to do what you're asking.

See also [Advanced Signals and Slots Usage](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/signalsandslots.html#advanced-signals-and-slots-usage) for more info and some examples.

Answer (score 0):

[QObject::sender()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#sender)
Edit: note the QSignalMapper reference there as well.

Comment: Thanks! I used signal mapper. How can I get the sender property?

Comment: Inside any slot, you can call QObject::sender(), that returns the object that ``called'' this slot. You can use static_cast<T>(QObject::sender()) to cast the returned object into T (where T is the type you want).